# Can java objects access their instance methods when coding in groovy?

Tags: java, json, grails, groovy

I have written two java classes, with a constructor and an instance method to return an JSON array. I want to access instance of these classes in groovy and call the getArray method on these objects I have instantiated. My problem is I do not know how to access those getArray methods?? Here is some code:

```
import JSONEncounterDesk;
import JSONHelpDesk;
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.json.JSONObject

    class UsersController {

        def index() { 
            JSONEncounterDesk currEncounterDesk = new JSONEncounterDesk();
            JSONHelpDesk currHelpDesk = new JSONHelpDesk();

            return render(contentType: 'text/json') {
                ret
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What's your Java code look like?  If the methods you want to call are public or package (and your Java classes are in same package as your Groovy class) than you should be able to access. It is unclear what problem you are having.

Comment: If your build tool is configured to compile both, than of course you can. Both Java and Groovy source files compile to Java bytecode. Did you even try compiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java object can *always* access *it's own* fields and methods. Doesn't matter how it was invoked or who invoked it.

**Update**

In almost any language that can have a reference to a Java object instance, any *public* method is accessible. Usually using the syntax `obj.methodName()`.

This includes, among many others: Groovy, JavaScript, JSP EL, JEXL, Scala, ...

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure that method getArray() is public. Java and groovy both compiles to generate a class you can access methods of both in any java or groovy. Just the access modifiers decides that are they accessible or not.